# Passing-through environment variables to Tomcat 7.0 web app context

Tags: variables, tomcat, environment, sudo, context.xml

Apache Tomcat 7.0, CentOS 5.8 i386

A web application needs a specific environment variable **XY** to be present in its context.
This variable is set in */etc/profile* as a result of a computation (i.e. not a static value) and it is also used by other native applications running on the same system (hence it has to be the environment variable approach).

Tomcat is started with a general script using a dedicated tomcat user and *sudo*.
The first problem of passing *XY* through *sudo* is solved (thanks to stackoverflow) with the explicit definition within */etc/sudoers*:

```
Defaults    env_keep ="XY"
```

It means that the environment variable *XY* is preserved by *sudo* which is not the default case.

Now the environment variable *XY* is visible in the tomcat process. This can be verified with *ps* and */proc/tomcat-PID/environ* or an explicit *echo $XY* in */your_tomcat/bin/startup.sh* (which is called by the init.d script using *sudo*). But seeing *XY* in the tomcat process does not mean the web app can see it. The web app dumps its environment to the log file with help of

```
LOGGER.debug("Environment: " + System.getenv());
```

the astonishing result for me was: no *XY* at all, although tomcat had it!

After reading the context documentation of tomcat 7.0 (be careful to distinguish between 7.0 and older versions of tomcat) I added the following entry to */your_tomcat/conf/context.xml*:

```
<Context>
...
<Environment name="XY" value="INIT_VALUE" type="java.lang.String"/>  
...
</Context>
```

Now the output of *System.getenv()* really contains my *XY* environment variable **BUT** it has the correct value from */etc/profile* not the value **INIT_VALUE** I specified in *context.xml*. With other words my */etc/profile* does overwrite the **INIT_VALUE**, which is what I needed but not what I expected as there is no word about this in the documentation.

Did I find un-docmented behaviour that might be removed in later versions of tomcat or is this the way to go?
So in the end I am happy having a working solution but I am not very confident that this is a recommended and proper way of passing-through environment variables.
Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Tomcat Environment entries are different from system environment variables. Environment Entries specified by `<Environment>` markup are JNDI, accessible using `InitialContext.lookup` under `java:/comp/env`, while `System.getEnv()` is about system environment variables (of the tomcat process itself).

Comment: Is there any way to have application specific environment variables (the same variable has a different value per application) without using JNDI ? I'm thinking of something like a -Dname=bob in an application specific context.

Comment: I did this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652264/tomcat-7-application-java-environment-variables-jndi-less/26653238#26653238